# jQuery dataTables custom buttons

Tags: jquery, button, datatable

Any way of creating two custom buttons: `Edit` and `Delete`, which then I can capture with `.click()`, or any other way, and do a `$.post()` for `Delete` and redirect to `http://site.com/admin/news/edit/1212` for `Edit`?

It's that I just implemented `dataTables()` and have a couple of thing that are missing from the initial version, and those buttons are one of them.

For example this is what I had before for the `Delete` event:

```
$('.delete_item').click(function(){
    $("input[name^='selector']:checked:enabled").each(function(index, value){
        var block = $(this).parent().parent();
        var id = $(this).parent().parent().find('.id').text();
        $.post(base_url+'admin/articles/delete/'+id,function(data) {
            if (data == true)
            {
                block.fadeOut('slow');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('there was an error, please try again');
            }
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to tell that for each row we have a column who have two buttons : edit and delete and when you click of them you do an action what you described ?

If yes,

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sThGk/101/) jsFiddle

you should do something like this :

first, create a form with your buttons and in your form, you are your datatable :

Ex:

#### html

```
<form type="post">
   <div><input id="button" type="button" value="delete" /></div>
   <div class="container">
        
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
       <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><span><input name="row_1" type="checkbox" value="id1" /></span></td>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                   Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td> 4</td>
            <td>X</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
        
   </div>
</form>
```

#### javascript

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
$('#button').click(function() {
  alert(JSON.stringify($('form').serialize()));
  //do you post here example :
  //$.ajax({
  //    url:base_url+'admin/articles/delete/',
  //    data: $('form').serializeArray(), // or $('form').serialize()
  //    type:'POST',
  //    dataType:'json'
  //}).done(function(data){
  //if (data)
  //{
  //   block.fadeOut('slow');
  //}
  //else
  //{
  //   alert('there was an error, please try again');
  //}
  //});
});
```

Is that it helped you?